# Can sybase be used with ruby-on-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Wondering about backends available with rails.

Does ruby-on-rails work with a sybase database?

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one configuration that should let a Rails application talk to Sybase. Use [JRuby](http://jruby.org) as your Ruby interpreter, and [active-record-jdbc-adapter](https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter) for your database adapter. You'll also need the [Sybase JDBC driver](http://www.sybase.com/products/allproductsa-z/softwaredeveloperkit/jconnect) installed. There may be other adapters that work with MRI or other Ruby interpreters.

There are other good reasons to choose JRuby over MRI in any case -- much better threading for one.